# The difference of Jira Epics and Components

Tags: manual-testing, defect-tracking, jira

I read on Jira documentation and do some research. However, i'm still a bit confused about Components and Epics. In a sample website like Facebook, it has features like Login, Register, Write A Post and Chat.

1. Now, should I put those as an Epic? or as a Component?
2. How should I categorize app's pages like Login page, Register page, Homepage and Timeline page? Should I also make it as an epic or a component?
3. If we will put User Timeline as an epic for example, how do we classify the features like Write On Friends Timeline, Mention a Friend on the timeline? Can we make it as a sub-epic?

I'm still new this software. I would appreciate every comment from you. It's much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it about project management software and not testing. Better asked on http://pm.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Epics and components are just like labels a way to group issues. What you use them for is for you to group them logically for you and your teams.

There is of-course some default terminology interpretation:

- **Epic**: Container for work that is larger than a single iteration. Usually a large user-story. I would describe that in "behavioural change" not in the form of login page. Users do not need a login page, they want to do some action, some behaviour. The login, but also register is mostly irrelevant, you can always build that later after you verified that the behaviour is something users need.
- **Component**: Often used as logical component (e.g. API, DB), but could also be functional components.

Epics are something you want to build, components are parts of your application that have been build.